# Build Java module and old jar for different Java versions from single source code

Tags: java, maven, java-8, java-module, java-17

I have Maven Java library project with target `1.8`. I want to convert it into Java module for modern clients but keep backward compatibility for old clients, and publish new releases for both clients:

```
 my-mod   my-lib
 -v0.3    -v0.3
    \    /
     \  /
      \/
   my-lib-v0.2
       |
   my-lib-v0.1
```

So my questions is how to correctly add `module-info.java` into an existing project and be able to compile it to `1.8` target, and how to configure Maven to deploy two releases for two Java versions, e.g. for `1.8` and `17`?

Answer (score 0):

Just create your `module-info.java` inside your package folder. It will be ignored by Java 8 and picked up by Java 9+. Maybe you would like to take a look at this nice blog post: https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity

Comment: Maven compile plugin is failing if I add this file in `src/main/java`: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project test: Compilation failure: modules are not supported in -source 8`

Comment: So you want the *same* JAR file containing classes build for different Java versions? That is a different question and answer. Therefore, you need to activate *multi-release*. A quick info about that can be found here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#multi-java-version-module-jar-files

Comment: no, I want to make two jars from one maven project (source code is compatible with 1.8): one jar with 1.8 target, and another jar with 17 target and modules support

Comment: In that case just have a look at the Maven manual: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html